# Сложный SQL запрос с подсчётом количества дочерних записей

Tags: sql

Имеется таблица

```
Tag (id, parent_id, title, status)
```

У всех тегов первого уровня установлен `NULL` в качестве `parent_id`. У дочерних в атрибуте `parent_id` указан `id` родителя из текущей таблицы (всё очевидно)

`status` - число (`smallint`)

Нужно составить SQL запрос, чтобы получить все теги вместе с количеством "детей" разных статусов. То есть чтобы на выходе получилось примерно следующее:

```
[
 'id' => 1, 
 'title' => 'tag1', 
 'count_of_status_1' => 2, 
 'count_of_status_2' => 4
],
[
 'id' => 9, 
 'title' => 'tag2', 
 'count_of_status_1' => 5, 
 'count_of_status_2' => 0
],
...
```

Всё должно быть написано на чистом `sql`.

Подскажите, как это возможно сделать, и возможно ли вообще? С sql знаком поверхностно. Только на уровне `Select ... from ... where`.

Comment: 1. Диалект SQL? 2. Максимальный уровень вложений фиксирован?

Comment: или мб надо получить количество только прямых потомков а не рекурсивно?

Comment: 1. Не понял вопрос. Не знаком с темой диалектов sql.
2. Смотреть только прямых потомков, без вложенностей.

Comment: P.S. Количество статусов - 5. То есть будет только 5 заранее известных полей типа "count_of_status_N"

Comment: диалект - название СУБД, которую вы используете, mysql, sql-server, oracle и т.д. либо если надо чистый стандарт ANSI SQL, то так и укажите. Решение этой задачи для разных СУБД будет выглядеть по-разному

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это стандартное отключение SQL:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title,
  SUM(CASE c.status WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Count status 1',
  SUM(CASE c.status WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Count status 2'
  FROM Tags AS p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Tags AS c
    ON c.parent_id = p.id
  WHERE p.parent_id IS NULL
  GROUP BY p.id, p.title
```

([демонстрация](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/abBucdmk76RZ7CseJ7eErm/0))

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tag.id,
       tag.title,
       (SELECT 
          COUNT(*) 
        FROM tag 
        WHERE parent_id = tag.id 
          AND status=1) as count_of_status_1,
       (SELECT 
          COUNT(*) 
        FROM tag 
        WHERE parent_id = tag.id 
          AND status=2) as count_of_status_2 
FROM tag
```